# Word (for MAC) VBA not the same?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

Is it true that some VBA commands/functions do not work on old Word for MAC versions? For example  **REPLACE Function (VBA)** that works on Word 2011 does not work (produces an error) on Word 2004.

Is there a way to make them work like the missing  **REPLACE Function (VBA)** function?